# Convention for CLI parameters specifying a string with variable substitution

Tags: command-line

There are some formalized and some unspoken conventions for CLIs, such as the uppercase being the default when prompting for a choice:

```
Do you want to eat the apple? (Y/n)
```

Is there a convention for specifying a string with variables substituted by the program, such as a file prefix:

E.g.

```
-p, --file-prefix  Output File Prefix with subsitution for %date and %author e.g. "myprefix-%date-%author-"
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what it is you're asking. I don't quite understand your example at the end.

Comment: I was asking about a convention of how to denote variables in CLI params that are substituted by the CLI tool in some way. E.g. "%varx%-staticString" vs "%varx-staticString" vs "$varx-staticString". So if there is some convention for CLI params that follow such a pattern.